# Magento 2.4.1 EE checkout and cart page blank with 400 products

Tags: checkout, cart, magento2.4.1

In magento2.4.1 EE I have added 400 products to cart. I click on proceed to checkout, getting blank page and cart page is also blank. My php_value memory_limit 756M php_value max_execution_time 18000 in .htaccess.

Comment: increase memory limit to 2048M

Comment: Done. but still not working.

Comment: @BaljitKaur Try to check logs.

Comment: @AmitSaini its just giving 
NOTICE: ##### NEW QUOTE ##### [] []NOTICE: Checking availability for quote #893884 [] []